# How can I allow access to a samba share on Windows 10 Pro coming from a different VLAN?

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba, vlan, windows-10-pro

Here is my configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro on 192.168.21.19 with a folder shared
- Brother printer on 192.168.55.34
- pfSense with FW rule that allows 192.168.55.34 to access any port/protocol on 192.168.21.19

My printer still cannot connect to the share. I have confirmed pfSense is letting the traffic through (I can see it in the logs).

I assume Windows 10 is not allowing access from different VLANs.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click start and search for "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" (if you can't find it try "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security").
2. Click on "Inbound Rules"
3. Scroll down to find rules beginning with "File and Printer Sharing" with "Private" in the Profile column. Double-click the first one.
4. Go to the "Scope" tab.
5. On the box that says "Remote IP address" (the bottom one), click the Add button.
6. In the new window that opens, tick the first option ("This IP address or subnet") and write the IP address of the device you wish to allow (your printer in this case).
7. Repeat steps 3 through 6 for every other "File and Printer Sharing" rule with "Private" profile.

If it still doesn't work, make sure your network profile is indeed private and not set to public network.